# not able to run firebase login command

Tags: html, firebase, powershell, deployment, prompt

not able to run firebase login cmn in command prompt in windows-11. it is showing the error-"you cannot run this script on the current system"

tried to run the command with flag --no-localhost, and also tried to gain the root access but no help

error-
firebase : File C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 is not digitally
signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.